# Just to confirm and share: how to apply for magento patch supee-5344

Tags: magento-1.9, security, patches, ftp, supee-5344

I found a possible solution for those who have no SSH access, or having difficulties using sh command to apply for the patch: (community edition)

With the successful update on the local machine, find the 5 files on your local machine which have the updates:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php

app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php

app/code/core/Mage/Oauth/controllers/Adminhtml/Oauth/AuthorizeController.php

app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Model/Observer.php

lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php
```

upload these files to your server using FTP, and patches are done!

To me, this is a safer option to apply for the patches.

Pls correct me if I am wrong! Hopefully it helps.

Comment: Are you using git/svn, any repository system?

Comment: No, I just applied the patch based on CE 1.9.1.0, and uploaded the files to the server.

Comment: Yes, then go to you `app/etc/` folder where you get one file regarding your patch, if that one is exist so than your patch is applied

Comment: I have already applied the patch this way. successful.

Answer (score 0):

Replace "upload these files to your server using FTP" with "deploy code from development to production" and this is the normal recommended workflow:

1. apply patch on development
2. test
3. deploy

Running the patch scripts on production is not a good idea since these patches often contain backwards incompatible changes or break extensions.

If you should use FTP for deployment is a different topic...